# Question on Compactness

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let the metric space be the real numbers with the usual distance formula. Let $E$ be an open interval from $1/8$ to $2$. Then $E$ would be compact if every open cover of $E$ has a finite cover. I know $E$ is *not* compact because it is not closed, but I'm not sure how to use the cover definition of compactness to prove it. The sets $(1/n, 1+1/n)$ where $n \in \{1, \ldots, 9\}$ is a finite open cover for $E$, but I am not sure how to find a cover where this does not hold.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I mean the sets {1,2}, {1/2,3/2}, {1/3, 4/3}... Is this not a valid cover?

Comment: A ha, yes. Generally speaking, a trick for finding an open cover with no finite subcover when dealing with an open interval is to approach one of the end-points by using an infinite number of open sets. In the example I suggested below, you can get arbitrarily close to $2$ with the open cover, but any *finite* subcover will necessarily omit points close to $2$.

Answer (score 1):

How about taking the open set $(1/8, 3/2)$ along with the sets $(1, 1 + \frac{n}{n+1})$ for $n \geq 1$?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Let $x_n$ be a sequence strictly increasing, which converges to $2$, use the sequence to define an open cover of the interval, and use the fact it is strictly increasing to prove there is no finite subcover.